# Hibernate 2nd level cache eviction

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, ehcache

I'm working on a Java Spring project where we have micro services architecture, each service has an internal cache of type hibernate second level cache implemented by Ehcache region factory, to insure data consistency between the different caches we use the Ehcache integration with JMS.
This is working so far, but how can I send manually a signal to the topic the caches queues are superscribed to, this signal should evict a specific cache region?
what is the nature and structure of such message in Java?

Comment: have you tried calling `entityManagerFactory.getCache().evict(MyEntity.class)`?

Comment: I'm afraid this will work on the service' local cache only, the other services (on other servers) will not be affected! I'll try it though just to be certain.

Comment: it internally calls `net.sf.ehcache.event.RegisteredEventListeners#notifyRemoveAll`, so, if it does not affect remote caches that means your cache setup is broken.